# Disable TSA lock allowed?

Tags: aircraft, tsa

I will be traveling from the Netherlands to Poland. I have a seperate TSA lock, but it is well known that those have a vulnerability because one can get easily hold of the TSA master key. I want to disable the TSA keyhole by, for instance, glueing it. I don't expect the TSA lock will be used, so can I get in trouble for this?

Comment: Other than any **thief** may become angry (and it is otherwise locked) , no. If any security needs to open the bag and it is unlocked should also pose no problem. No idea what happens when security needs to open a locked piece of luggage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to disable the TSA keyhole by, for instance, glueing it. I don't expect the TSA lock will be used, so can I get in trouble for this?

No. If security needs to open it when you're not present (this is very rare) then it's the same as any other luggage without a TSA lock.

If you are present then they'll just ask you to open it. If you're at customs somewhere and you cannot open it (again, similar to a non-TSA bag you cannot open) then they'll have tools to do so (i.e. forcing some part of the luggage, likely rendering it unusable) or they can confiscate the luggage.

Comment: Many people do not bother to lock their luggage, just close it such that it can not fall open.

Comment: @Willeke yea, they'll probably try that first if they need to break into it. I don't think they often do that for no reason though, so as long as there's nothing special about it (or the passenger associated with it) they'll just leave it alone.

Answer (score 2):

Do not glue it. Use an other lock. [This is just for infra-european flights]

For all inspections, you are required to be present (also for security: if it contains a bomb, you will *get* it). [But this is also a disadvantage, if they fail to find you, e.g. in an airport with non-speaker notification), you will be denied to board, if the baggage cannot be checked and loaded on time.

For the few cases they will not require you, they will have no problem to open your case (and possibly it is the least of your problems) (braking the lock, the luggage).

But do not carry valuable in your baggage. A good lock will tell staff that you have valuable stuff in it.

Personally I never used a lock, and I never got anything stolen (very many countries and continents, some not really safe, or well know to be used to corruption, also on customs).